# Nginx, passenger, rails - how to configure for long running requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, nginx, passenger

My situation is like this:
1. User uploads 150MB zip file, with 600 files inside. It takes 4 minutes or so to upload the file to the server.
2. Server processes the file contents, takes 70 seconds or so.
3. The server responds with Service Unavailable, with a log like, "could not forward the response to the client... stop button was clicked"
4. The Rails application log says, 200 OK response was returned.

So, I am guessing it must be a problem within one of Nginx or Passenger that is causing it return with the error even thought it is going fine inside the Rails app. My suspect is a timeout setting, because I could reproduce it by just putting a sleep of 180 seconds inside the long running method and doing nothing.

I will appreciate if you guys know what specific nginx/passenger config may fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using S3 as your storage you may consider using something like carrierwave_direct to skip passing the file through the web server and instead upload directly to S3.

Like noted above you could incorporate a queueing process like delayed_job.

https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct

Answer (score 1):

I presume that `nginx` is the public-facing server and it proxies requests through to another server running your RoR application for you. If this assumption is correct, you may need to increase the value of your `nginx` [`proxy_read_timeout`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_read_timeout) setting for the specific locations that are causing you trouble.

Comment: To clarify: somewhere during your Step 2, `nginx` gets bored with waiting for a response from `passenger`, and sends a `503` back to the client. Some time after that, Rails finishes and sends a `200` back to `nginx`, but this doesn't get forwarded to the client since `nginx` has already sent a response.

Comment: I tried the proxy_read_timeout and it didn't help. Its a bit frustrating at this stage, cause I only see this issue in prod and not in my dev environment running nginx/passenger.

Comment: I'm with the same problem and don't have access to nginx config on amazon Elastic Beanstalk =(. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

For long run request, I think you should return an 'please wait' page immediately and make the processing background. After the processing is completed, set the task in the database as 'completed'. Within the period, whenever user refresh the page, return 'please wait' immediately. After completed, return the result. You can set an autorefresh timeout in the page to refresh the page after an estimated period.

Answer (score 0):

I'd instantly store the upload somewhere and redirect to a "please wait" page which asks for the status of the background processing and could even display some progress bar then, e.g. using ajax.

For the actual background processing I'd recommend DelayedJob which worked great for us and supports easy job deployment and implementation.